# Cannot vote to delete in first post review queue?

Tags: discussion

Question title says it all.

I was going through the first post review queue, saw and "answer" I deemed worthy of deletion (and I have that privilege) but that was not one of the options. I downvoted and flagged it and moved on.

Once the queue was cleared, I went back over to that thread and voted to delete it.

Is that the intended workflow? Should I have done anything differently?

Answer (score 3):

For [trusted users](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), you can still vote to delete a post from First Post/Late Answer review queues just like the usual: **the answer needs to have a negative score first**. (Very Low Quality review queue is an exception which is the only review queue with a possibility to delete 0-score answers)

Just like from outside the review queues, downvoting an answer to negative score doesn't automatically show the "delete" link; you have to refresh the page to see it.

This is the same for inside those review queues: **downvote the answer, refresh the page, then click "delete" link.**